# LocalStorage not found nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to nextjs and I need to inject all data that I got from my Api everything work but I have some request who are still in unauthorized.

To access to my api i need a bearer token, i stock it in the localstorage, I tried to recover it from the file _app.js and because in the first few refresh the value is undifined all of my early request are in 401 state.

So my question is where could i do it because i think i'm to deep in the architecture and it has to be in another place

_app.js

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Api from '../src/components/Api/Api';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const api = new Api({ baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEURL });
  useEffect(function () {
    /* Loading the token from the local storage. */
    api.loadToken();
    /* Testing the token to see if it is valid. */
    const response = api.testToken();
    if(response !== "ok"){
      Router.push("/auth/login")
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>{pageProps.title}</title>
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} api={api} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: This probably needs more details, but have you tried moving `const api = new Api(...);` inside the `useEffect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem, i tried to do a custom system but nextJS give us a way to it via DataFetching -> [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing your token as a cookie which can be read and processed through `_middleware`. At least, this is the best strategy I could come up with given the stack that you have described.